# mysql merge primary key

Tags: mysql, merge, foreign-key-relationship

What is the best way to merge records that have foreign keys.
There are a lot of topics on "merging records" but they are mostly selecting and grouping rows.
This can obviously be done in code, but a safe database solution would have to be more efficient.

This is the best solution I can think of. A transaction in a stored procedure.
Turn off foreign key checks.
Update all the foreign keys.
Delete the duplicate record.

Does anyone have a better way of doing this?
Or is there any other checks that also need to be done to maintain key integrity?

**Database example - untested**

User 'John Doe' (id_user=2, duplicate id = 5) accidentally made a second account and wants to merge all the data with the original account.

**tbl_users**

```
id_user  | first_name | last_name
1        | John       | Doe
2        | Jane       | Doe
3        | john       | Smith
4        | Jane       | Smith
5        | John       | Doe
6        | Blah       | Meh
```

**tbl_likes**

```
id_user   | apple | orange
2         | 1     | 0
5         | 1     | 1
```

**tbl_random**

```
id_user   | col1   | col2
1         | Aaa    | Bbb
3         | Ccc    | Ddd
5         | Eee    | Fff


DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `tns_merge_user` (IN id_user_old INT, IN id_user_new INT)
    BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;

    START TRANSACTION;

        # Prevent other queries modifying tables during merge
        LOCK TABLES tbl_users WRITE;
        LOCK TABLES tbl_likes WRITE;
        LOCK TABLES tbl_random WRITE;

        #Disable foreign key checks
        SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

        # Perform merge queries on related tables
        UPDATE tbl_likes SET id_user = id_user_new;
        UPDATE tbl_random SET id_user = id_user_new;

        # Delete duplicate user record
        DELETE FROM tbl_users WHERE id_user = id_user_old;

        # Re-enable foreign key checks
        SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
        UNLOCK TABLES;

    COMMIT;
END
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

So I haven't received any answers.
I got around to doing development tests. But haven't used it in production yet.

**schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `_test_profile` (
    `id_profile` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_profile__merge` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_profile`),
    KEY `idx__id_profile__merge` (`id_profile__merge`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `_test_email` (
    `id_email` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_profile` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `type` enum('primary','postal') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_email`),
    KEY `idx_id_profile` (`id_profile`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk__test_email__id_profile` FOREIGN KEY (`id_profile`) REFERENCES `_test_profile` (`id_profile`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `_test_address` (
    `id_address` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_profile` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `address` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_address`),
    KEY `idx_id_profile` (`id_profile`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk__test_address__id_profile` FOREIGN KEY (`id_profile`) REFERENCES `_test_profile` (`id_profile`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Test inserts**

```
INSERT INTO _test_profile(`name`) VALUES
    ('test01'),
    ('test02'),
    ('test03');

INSERT INTO _test_email(id_profile,`type`,`email`) VALUES
    (1,'primary','test01@primary.com'),
    (2,'primary','test02@primary.com'),
    (2,'postal', 'test02@primary.com'),
    (3,'postal','test03@primary.com');

INSERT INTO _test_address(id_profile,`address`) VALUES
    (1,'Address One'),
    (2,'Address Two');
```

**Merging Transaction**

Needs to be wrapped in a stored procedure with a variable confirming if it worked or not. When I get around to proper testing I will edit this answer with the full stored procedure code for future reference.

```
START TRANSACTION;

    # Prevent other queries modifying tables during merge
    LOCK TABLES _test_profile WRITE;

    #Disable foreign key checks
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

    # Modify record to be merged into
    UPDATE _test_profile
    SET id_profile__merge = 1, id_profile = 0
    WHERE id_profile =1;

    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

    # Modify record to be merged into
    UPDATE _test_profile
    SET id_profile = 1
    WHERE id_profile =3;

    #Disable foreign key checks
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

    # Delete duplicate user record
    DELETE FROM _test_profile WHERE id_profile = 1;

    # Modify record to be merged into
    UPDATE _test_profile
    SET id_profile = 1, id_profile__merge = 0
    WHERE id_profile__merge =1;

    # Re-enable foreign key checks
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
    UNLOCK TABLES;

COMMIT;
```

---

I won't post untested code in this answer, but will have it in my git profile once fully functional.